# Prestashop payment methods is empty in backoffice

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am running a Prestashop 1.7.5.2 and i have 4 payment methods : paypal, monetico etc..
On the backoffice, payment -> payment methods -> the listing is empty!

[image: prestashop screen shot]

I can't figure out why ! any one facing this issue ?

Thanks

I tried reviewing payments and shipments settings everything is ok from my end but still not showing. tried also clearing cache not helping. Tried seeking for missing entries in _module_carrier db table but all good here. Also checked if all carriers have different names to avoid conflicts.

Comment: This page is not important as it only lists Payment modules installed, but you can find them all on Modules page.
The important page is Payment > Preferences. If you can see and configure all your payment methods there, this is all that matters.